# leafletjs get coordinates from onLocationFound function

Tags: geolocation, leaflet, coordinates

I am working with leafletjs API.

I do not have experience with JS and I couldn't find any answer here.

I am trying to combine using geolocation service with leaflet routing service.

My goal is to get

> latlng

value from

> onLocationFound

function and passed that

information to first

> waypoint

in routing service.

```js
//INITIALIZE MAP...
var map = L.map('map');

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
 attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
// LOCATION SERVICE 
map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 16});
function onLocationFound(e) {
    var radius = e.accuracy / 2;
     L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map)


}
 

map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);

function onLocationError(e) {
    alert(e.message);
}

map.on('locationerror', onLocationError);
//End of Location service, 
//GET LATLNG PARAMETERS AFTER CLICK IN CONSOLE
map.on('click', function(e)  
  {

  tempLatitude = e.latlng.lat;

  tempLongitude = e.latlng.lng;
  console.log(tempLongitude);
console.log(tempLatitude);
});


// ROUTING SERVICE
var control = L.Routing.control(L.extend(window.lrmConfig, {


  waypoints: [
 L.latLng(57.74, 11.94),
  L.latLng(57.6792, 11.949)
 ],
 geocoder: L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim(),
 routeWhileDragging: true,
 reverseWaypoints: true,
 showAlternatives: true,
 altLineOptions: {
  styles: [
   {color: 'black', opacity: 0.15, weight: 9},
   {color: 'white', opacity: 0.8, weight: 6},
   {color: 'blue', opacity: 0.5, weight: 2}
  ]
 }
})).addTo(map);





L.Routing.errorControl(control).addTo(map);
```

.

Comment: Are you including the Leaflet script on your page?

Comment: Yes, this is mine index.js file, I have include all javascripts in html.
Code is working fine and geolocation too.
I just need to get latlng from onLocationFound function.

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint in your code inside the click handler function to make sure it's firing and inspect the properties of "e"?